# Is there a machine learning algorithm to deal with this problem?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, recommendation-engine

Let's say that we have a database where each row includes:

- a **person vector** such as `(1,0, ..., 1)`
- a **movie vector** `(1,1, ..., 0)`
- the **rating** that the person gave to the content

What machine learning algorithm would be able to establish a movie ranking based on the user vector ?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: what exactly the `person` and `movie` vectors represent?

Comment: There are many algorithms for that - it's a whole field - look up "recommender systems".

Comment: The **person vector** represents attributes such as the `mood, age`...  While the **movie vector** represents attributes like the `topic, comedy, drama`...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit vague. But I will try to answer. So it looks like what you are asking is if you already have the latent factors what algorithms can be used. How did you obtain these latent factors? are these part of the dataset. If they are not derived and given it is going to be hard for you to predict the movie rating from these given data. Do you have ratings as part of this data set. Then combining this you can use MF or Clustering to obtain movie rankings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! These latent factors and the ratings are part of the dataset. For a person vector I have a movie vector and the rating given.

Comment: If you have latent factors already available. Then its matter of obtaining rating using R=UV^T